# Structure declaration and definition in C

Tags: c, struct, compilation, declaration, definition

If we write something like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    unsigned int counter;
} MyStruct;
```

This represents structure declaration?

Declaration says our compiler that somewhere there is a structure which have parameters of type and size like above,  and no space is reserved in memory for that structure in case of declaration.

and definition is, as now we reserved a space in memory for our structure:

```
MyStruct tmpStruct;
```

Or I am wrong?

Please clarify the situation with structures.

Comment: Pay attention to tags ... it's C or C++  not CSS ...

Comment: Yes, sorry I am writing from cellphone.

Comment: and for your question you are somehow correct ... first you define a new type so there is nothing in memory, then when you declare variable using this type you will allocate the needed space in memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different kinds of definitions in C - type definitions, variable definitions, and function definitions. Types and functions could also be declared without being defined.

Your `typedef` is not a declaration, it's a definition of a *type*. In addition to defining a `struct` with no tag, it defines a type name that corresponds to that `struct`.

A declaration of a `struct` would look like this:

```
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
```

This would let you declare pointers to `MyStruct`, forward-declare functions that take `MyStruct*`, and so on:

```
void foo(MyStruct* p);
```

What you have is a declaration/definition of a variable of type `MyStruct`:

```
MyStruct tmpStruct;
```

Here is a complete example with `struct`'s declaration separated from its definition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Here is a declaration
typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;
// A declaration lets us reference MyStruct's by pointer:
void foo(MyStruct* s);
// Here is the definition
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
};
// Definition lets us use struct's members
void foo(MyStruct *p) {
    printf("%d %d\n", p->a, p->b);
}

int main(void) {
    // This declares a variable of type MyStruct
    MyStruct ms = {a:100, b:120};
    foo(&ms);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/4zPmu0)

Comment: This reads like an "advanced user's guide" which is beyond the level of the question. What are the unnecessary `a:` and `b:` for in the `struct` initialisation?

Comment: @WeatherVane I figured I'd include `a:` an `b:` to get readers curious about designated initializers - a feature that has been around for a while, yet does not see a widespread use. As far as OP's level of understanding goes, I can't figure it out by a single post.

Comment: All well and good but you seem to contradict OP's belief, which is essentially correct.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, I shouldn't say OP's view is entirely correct, although it's certainly not incorrect. I figured I should mention a few important things to him to complete his picture of the C world.

Comment: A declaration of a struct does not look like that, that is a typedef declaration!  Declaration of a struct is simply struct tagname { members...}; and if you instantiate it you keep the word struct.

Answer (score 3):

There is a great write-up on this over here

https://www.microforum.cc/blogs/entry/21-how-to-struct-lessons-on-structures-in-c/

The first thing you declared up there is a type declaration combined with a structure declaration, no definition so no space allocated correct.

The proper way to declare a struct is to say :

```
   struct MyStruct
   {
      unsigned int counter; 
   };
```

You can now do a definition of an instance like this:

```
   struct Mystruct myVariableStructInstance = {1234};  // Define struct instance with initializer
```

It is also possible to combine the declaration with a definition like this :

```
   struct MyStruct_t
   {
      unsigned int counter; 
   }  MyStructVariable;
```

This will declare the structure type (struct MyStruct_t) and also define/instantiate a struct variable for you named  MyStructVariable

You can now pass MyStructVariable into a function declared thus:

```
void myFunction(struct MyStruct_t  temp);
```

Which you will call simply with

```
myFunction(MyStructVariable);
```

But really, read that blog post, it explains a lot more than just this!